# Which are the European countries that levy a financial transaction tax on stocks and how much?

Tags: taxes, stocks, european-union, europe, transaction

Financial transaction tax has been talked about in the past years in Europe. There are many countries in Europe. Some agree, some disagree. I have problems following this issue. As of today, which are the European countries that levy a financial transaction tax on stocks? How much is the tax as a percentage of the stocks value?

Comment: I don't follow it, but I think _none_ as of today. Taxing _transactions_ would simply take them off the market for any stock exchange activity, so I doubt they'll ever do it. It is probably some politician's pipe dream.

Comment: @Aganju France levies a transaction tax, so not exactly a pipe dream.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_transaction_tax#France